# Is a map from a closed surface to 3-space differentiable at the pre-image of a branch point?

Tags: differential-topology, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

Let $S$ be a closed surface and let $f$ be a map from $S$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $f(S)$ is a generic surface. The singularity set of $S$ contains double points, triple points and branch points. The branch point has a neighborhood homeomorphic to a cone over a figure eight. Is the map $f$  differentiable at the pre-image of a branch point? I think no, because we can not assign an orientation normal vector to a branch point, right?

Comment: You have to decide what "generic" means. Usually, this is defined by considering the space of smooth maps from a surface, which makes your question meaningless.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I got confused when I read that orientation normal vectors can be assigned to all points of the generic surface except at branch points, then I wondered why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$
f: \Bbb S^2 \to \Bbb R^3 : (x, y, z) \mapsto (x^3, y, z)
$$
The domain of $f$ is a surface; the image of $f$ is also a surface. The singularity set of $f$ contains all points of the sphere where $x = 0$, because the rank of the differential at those points is $1$. So the claim that the singularity set of $S$ consists of double, triple and branch points is mistaken.

If that statement -- that the singularity set consists of those things -- was meant to be an additional hypothesis, the answer is still "no". The Steiner surface, given by 
$$
f(x, y, z) = (xy, yz, zx)
$$
on the unit sphere, is clearly differentiable at every point (it's polynomial!), but the image surface contains several points whose neighborhoods look like a cone on a figure-8.

Comment: I mean the singularity set contains at most these three types of singularities. We may have a generic surface with no triple points or branch points for example.

Comment: OK. Well, the Steiner surface is still a counterexample. And your argument doesn't really make sense, because the surface $S$ could be nonorientable, in which case assigning an orientation normal could be impossible anyhow!